# finding some errors in making a toolbar using MFC

Tags: c++

i added this in my header file

```
CToolBar myBar;
public:
int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
void OnToolBarButton1();
void OnToolBarButton2();
```

and i added this in .cpp file

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CtoolbarfDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_COMMAND(IDC_TBBUTTON1,OnToolBarButton1)
    ON_COMMAND(IDC_TBBUTTON2,OnToolBarButton2)  
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CtoolbarfDlg::OnToolBarButton1()
   {

   }
   void CtoolbarfDlg::OnToolBarButton2()
   {

   }

 int CtoolbarfDlg::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
   {
       if (CDialog::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
           return -1;

       if (!myBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP
          | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC))
      {
            TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar");
            return -1; // fail to create
      }

     myBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR1);
     myBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
     EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
     DockControlBar(&myBar);
   }
```

i got these errors :(
error C3861: 'EnableDocking': identifier not found
error C3861: 'DockControlBar': identifier not found

Answer (score 0):

Based on `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CtoolbarfDlg, CDialog)`, your `CtoolbarfDlg` class inherits from `CDialog`, not from `CToolBar`. Since `EnableDocking()` and `DockControlBar()` are methods of the `CToolBar` class, there is no definition for them in your class, which is why you see this error.

If your class does indeed inherits from CToolBar (you did not post the complete class declaration from your .h file, so I cannot know for sure), then BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP should reflect that by being `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CtoolbarfDlg, CToolBar)`.

Just to make sure I'm clear, the problematic lines in your code are

```
EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
DockControlBar(&myBar);
```

not

```
myBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR1);
myBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
```

which are fine because myBar is a CToolBar instance.